# How to enable webgl in android studio emulator?

Tags: android, webgl

I'm user android emulatoк шт android studio ver 2.3.3
after start emulator Nexus_6_API_22 ( android 5.1 api 22 ) open in webbrowser webglreport.com
and see

[image]

Tell me please how to enable webgl.

Answer (score 0):

See this page [webview support list - html5](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/overview) .

You must update your webview control on ver 36 .
Better is to use chrome frame for android .

Also : https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/migrating.html

"Android 4.4 (API level 19) introduces a new version of WebView that is based on Chromium. "

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {

```
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        mWebRTCWebView = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_main_webview);

        setUpWebViewDefaults(mWebRTCWebView);

        mWebRTCWebView.clearCache(true);

        //Loading page
        mWebRTCWebView.loadUrl(main_url_address);

        mWebRTCWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

            @Override
            public void onPermissionRequest(final PermissionRequest request) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onPermissionRequest");
                getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                       request.grant(request.getResources());

                    }
                });
            }

        });

        return rootView;
    }



 @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
        private void setUpWebViewDefaults(WebView webView) {
            WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();

            // Enable Javascript
            settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

            // Use WideViewport and Zoom out if there is no viewport defined
            settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
            settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);

            // Enable pinch to zoom without the zoom buttons
            settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

            // Allow use of Local Storage
            settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);

            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                // Hide the zoom controls for HONEYCOMB+
                settings.setDisplayZoomControls(false);
            }

            // Enable remote debugging via chrome://inspect
            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
            }

            webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

            // AppRTC requires third party cookies to work
            CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
            cookieManager.setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(mWebRTCWebView, true);

            settings.setUserAgentString("mobile chrome android webgl");

            //JS INTERFACE
           // mWebRTCWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new JS_INTERFACE(getContext()), "android");

        }
```